# Random occurrence on fresh boot: Failed to generate a user instance of the SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for this user instance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 / 2012 Express with Visual Studio 2010 on my development PC. This error can also happen on deployment, and begin seeing this issue when running Windows 10 Prox64.

I never encountered this when running Windows 7 Pro x64. The unusual nature of this error, unlike many of the posts I've seen, is it usually occurs when booting or re-booting the PC - but not all the time. If I start the application again (without rebooting), 90% (estimate) of the time, it will connect and everything works.

I've tried some of the answers in other posts to delete the data in the `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data` folder, but that actually prevented the server from connecting at all.

Here is the connections string:

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="FrameworkAndDatabase.Properties.Settings.FVLocalDBConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB\FVLocalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Connection Timeout=60"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

I thought perhaps it was a time out issue, so I added the `Connection Timeout = 60` and tried various timeouts from 60 to 60000 and made no difference. I also thought perhaps the HDD disk drive had a read error and to a long time, but even happens with a SSD.

I am not sure what to try and how to fix it. It's more of an annoyance, but would be nice to have it work 100% of the time.

Here is the SQL Error log for 3 logon attempts:

```
2021-08-23 17:16:13.32 Server      Server resumed execution after being idle 28597 seconds: user activity awakened the server. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2021-08-23 17:16:14.96 Logon       Error: 15372, Severity: 16, State:
2021-08-23 17:16:14.96 Logon       Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed. [CLIENT: <local machine>]    
2021-08-23 17:19:51.66 Logon       Error: 15372, Severity: 16, State:
2021-08-23 17:19:51.66 Logon       Failed to generate a user instance of  SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user  instance. The connection will be closed. [CLIENT: <local machine>] 

2021-08-23 17:19:51.81 Logon       Error: 15372, Severity: 16, State: 
2021-08-23 17:19:51.81 Logon       Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

2021-08-23 17:21:24.42 Server      Server resumed execution after being idle 12 seconds: user activity awakened the server. This is an informational message only. No user action is required
```

Comment: Why are you using these discontinued versions? Even User Instance databases are obsolete now, replaced by [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) *several* years ago.

Comment: Are you trying to use LocalDB with the wrong connection string? To [connect to a specific file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#connect-to-the-automatic-instance) you need to use `Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=D:\Data\MyDB1.mdf`, not `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;...`

Comment: SQL Server doesn't start instantly. It has to mount and verify all system and user database files before it starts accepting network connections. For your own education, have a read through SQL Server's [ERRORLOG file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log) to see how long this takes - each task is timestamped.

Comment: 1) This is an older s/w that I am trying to maintain, and not sure what other consequences could arise if updating the sql server.   2) If I had the incorrect connection string, it would never work, not just randomly it would not.  3) I will post the error log which shows the time stamp of events, and when if fails.  I am not sure what all the entries mean, but in this case on 8/23/21, after the 3rd attempt it did connect. Any advice on how check if it is fully started, assuming that is the issue.